# How do I make my UITableView cells always == nil when viewWillAppear happens? I want to completely reload all my cell views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

How do I make my UITableView cells == nil (make them not cached) when viewWillAppear happens? I want to completely reload all my cell views every time I come to the view. The main reason is because the backgroundView image of the cells may changed because of "themes" I'm adding to the app.

`[tblView reloadData]` doesn't work on the cached views on the cell.

Comment: Reloaddata should work, you probably have a problem in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: @jrturton You are right. He has probably some other problem. reloadData does exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

Your cellForRowAtIndexPath method in your table view controller probably has two lines like:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

These lines attempt to reuse a previously created/formatted cell. To stop this reuse, take these lines out and instead just always allocate a new cell (i.e. something the equivalent of below).

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Then when you do [tableView reloadData] in your viewWillAppear method it will always create brand new cells for each row rather than trying to reuse old ones.

Comment: Yes it can, but thats a whole other topic - a variety of factors could come into play as to whether it is correct or not to reuse the cells and also how much performance impact, if any, not reusing will have.  If the cells are loaded from nibs then reuse would certainly be desirable, the overhead of an alloc and some minor configuration not necessarily that significant.  Overall though I agree that the goal is to make the cellForRowAtIndexPath method as inexpensive as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call **reloadData**, just let **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:** return 0 first.

Then your table will have no row at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` to determine and set the background views of your cell right before their drawn on screen. Obviously you'll want to use your datasource to determine which background view should be displayed.